S3 permission error in Databricks job run
I have set up a instance profile in databricks that allows me to connect to s3 using the following instructions:
https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/storage/tutorial-s3-instance-profile.html
I am able to run s3 in a databricks notebook, but when I try to run the same notebook as part of a job on the same cluster, I get an error like:
Run result unavailable: run failed with error message Cannot access AWS bucket

Looking through the spark logs I see:
24/05/29 06:39:30 WARN FileSystem: Failed to initialize fileystem dbfs:///: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Bucket user-workspace-s3-bucket does not exist
24/05/29 06:39:30 ERROR DbfsHadoop3: Failed to close FileSystem
java.lang.NullPointerException

Would anyone have clues on why this is happening and/or how to fix?

Check if the IAM role attached to the instance profile has policies that allow S3 access. The policies should include actions like s3:GetObject, s3:ListBucket, and others necessary for your operations.
Go to your cluster in Databricks.
Under the "Advanced Options" tab, check the "AWS Configuration" section.
Ensure the correct instance profile ARN is entered in the "IAM role" field.


The "Access Denied" error you are seeing is likely due to insufficient permissions to read the S3 bucket. The configurations you've set up are correct for accessing S3 using temporary AWS credentials, but the credentials themselves or the permissions associated with those credentials might not have sufficient access to the S3 bucket.

Bucket is not configured to block all public access.

The error message indicates that the bucket user-workspace-s3-bucket does not exist. Please verify the bucket name and its existence in your AWS S3.


